# AJAX dropdown within toggle(function) only works once

Tags: javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu, toggle

I have a table where rows are dynamically added.

In one of the cells I would like to toggle between a dropdown and an input box.

The dropdown is a PHP file loaded via AJAX. The issue is the dropdown only renders once.
First time you click the toggle button, the dropdown appears, as it should.
Second click switches it to the input field, as it should.
Third click does nothing, it just stays on the input box and does not toggle back to the dropdown.

If I comment out the AJAX call and put in a simple dropdown, it toggles back and forth just fine. So I believe the issue is with the AJAX portion.

Link to http://jsfiddle.net/6h5BD/1/
NOTE: the AJAX is currently commented out in jsfiddle and replaced with a temp dropdown so you can see what results I am looking for.

The portion of JS in question:

```
  $('input[name="button"]').toggle(function() {
      $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/brandDropdown.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(output_string){
            $('#brand').html(output_string);
             } 
      }); 
   }, function() {
       $(this).closest('td').prev().html("<input type=\"text\" name=\"itemBrand[]\" id=\"itemBrand\" size=\"10\" placeholder=\"New Brand\" style=\"text-transform: uppercase\"/>");
 });
```

The PHP:

```
  $sqlbrand = "SELECT BRD_Name FROM Brands ORDER BY BRD_Name asc";
  $resultbrand = odbc_exec($conn, $sqlbrand);
  ECHO "<select name='itemBrand[]' style='width:120px' size='1'>";
  while ($rowbrand = odbc_fetch_array($resultbrand)) {
      echo "<option value='".$rowbrand['BRD_Name']."'>".$rowbrand['BRD_Name']."</option>";
  }
  echo "</select></td>";
```

I am very open to handling this in a different manner. I have tried several different approaches, but to no avail.

Thank you in advanced for any assistance with this issue.

Comment: I've had problems using `toggle` with callbacks. Perhaps you could disable the input, show a spinner (or some sort of feedback) and make the AJAX request and then update the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant completely help you debug if I can't see the PHP file.

But from the HTML/JS I can see a potential problem. You are selecting **$("#brand")** and changing the html to the output_string. But when you are cloning your rows, you are making multiple divs with **id** of #brand and **ids** are supposed to be unique, you should use **class** instead.

Can you try if this works?

```
$('input[name="button"]').toggle(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/brandDropdown.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(output_string){
                 $this.closest('td').prev().html(output_string);
            } 
      }); 
   }, function() {
       $(this).closest('td').prev().html("<input type=\"text\" name=\"itemBrand[]\" id=\"itemBrand\" size=\"10\" placeholder=\"New Brand\" style=\"text-transform: uppercase\"/>");
 });
```

Comment: Good catch. I had already made that change of $this.closest('td').prev().html(output_string); on my site, I just didn't update the jsfiddle with the correct code, sorry.

Comment: Actually this is the solution. What I did not do, was create the variable var $this = $(this);
Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 0):

In your code (in the fiddle)

```
$(this).closest('td').prev().html(...)
```

should be

```
$(this).closest('td').prev().find('#brand').html(...)
```

because `$(this).closest('td').prev().html(...)` is replacing the html of `td` which means it's just removing the `div` with id `#brand` from within the `td` so in your `ajax` success callback `$('#brand').html(output_string);` is not working because it's not inside the `td` once you toggled it.

Comment: What you are saying make sense to me, but oddly, it does not work when I test it.
$(this).closest('td').prev().html(...) works fine though.

Comment: @user1816960, Glad to know that it has been solved but it really sounds odd to me too :-)

Comment: @user1816960, Just in case you need an example then [you may test it](http://jsfiddle.net/6h5BD/2/).